# c# how to teleport to where I want

Tags: c#

how to teleport to where I want? for example like this,,

```
else if (this.inputLine.StartsWith("/teleport"))


 ...............................  transform.position = new Vector3(71,79,-79);




 how to put 71,79,-79 after command? so like this,
  else if (this.inputLine.StartsWith("/teleport 71 79 -79"));

use (Convert.ToInt32(this.inputLine.Remove(0, 3))???? how? please help me
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the string? [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I recall seeing `DR SPOCK` having a method to help you accomplish this..

Comment: One of the Harry Potter movies tells you the the secret....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give very much information in your question, but from your code I'm assuming the following:

1. You're using Unity3D
2. You have a text input control that allows the user to enter commands.
3. Your `if-else` block cycles through all possible commands and completes the required action.
4. In this case, you are wanting to teleport to the location within the game that matches the value the user enters after entering "/teleport".

I suggest taking the string input and shortening it, then parsing the remaining string using the `' '` separator.
This will give you a string array with the vector values.
Next, convert each string in this array to an int, and then you can assign these ints to variables to be used in determining a new location.

For example:

```
// Input: /teleport 30 146 18

else if (this.inputLine.StartsWith("/teleport")
{
    // Gets what the user typed.
    string input = inputLine.Text;
    // Removes the "/teleport" part of string.
    string vectorString = input.Substring(8);
    // Splits the remaining string into an array of values using ' ' delimiter.
    string[] va = vectorString.Split(' ');
    // Converts values from string to int.
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(va[0]);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(va[1]);
    int z = Convert.ToInt33(va[2]);
    // Changes the position using these ints.
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

As an alternative to creating a substring, you could split the string and then avoid using the first element of the array, assigning elements 2, 3, and 4 to the ints instead.

Comment: can u help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394759/how-to-teleport-to-another-player-with-id